# authStateListener acting buggy, showing wrong user data upon login

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, listener

**EDITED**

My goal is to have a user sign up and when they segue to the tableview, the previous user's data doesn't show up. I have one main `authStateListener` in my `SceneDelegate`. It resides in a function like so:

```
func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
    
    // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    self.window = window

    let auth = Auth.auth()

    
    auth.addStateDidChangeListener { (_, user) in
        if let usersignedin = user {
            print(usersignedin.email)

            db.document("student_users/\(user?.uid)").getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("\(error)")
                } else {
                    let docSnap = docSnapshot?.exists
                    guard docSnap! else {
                        let alreadyLoggedInAsASchoolViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.SchoolEventDashboardStoryboardID) as! SchoolTableViewController
                        let navigationizedSchoolVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: alreadyLoggedInAsASchoolViewController)
                        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationizedSchoolVC
                        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
                        return
                    }
                 
                    let alreadyLoggedInAsAStudentViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.StudentEventDashboardStoryboardID) as! StudentSegmentedTableViewController
                    let navigationizedVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: alreadyLoggedInAsAStudentViewController)
                    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationizedVC
                    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
                
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("No user is signed in")
            let notLoggedInAtAll = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.StoryboardIDs.GothereMainMenuStoryboardID) as! GothereMainMenuViewController
            let navMainMenu = UINavigationController(rootViewController: notLoggedInAtAll)
            self.window!.rootViewController = navMainMenu
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }


}
```

This is what I use to navigate the user to the right vc when the app launches and also for push notification handling. Now the function works fine, but when I log out and log in as a different user, the previous user's data is populating the cells. This is also the case after a new user signs up.

This is the function I use to populate the cells in the tableView:

```
func getEventName() {
    listener.documentListener = db.collection(Constants.Firebase.schoolCollectionName).order(by: "time_created", descending: true).addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("There was an error fetching the data: \(error)")
        } else {
            self.events = querySnapshot!.documents.map { document in
                return EventName(eventName: (document.get("event_name") as! String))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } 
    }
}
```

The path's raw value works fine:

`static let schoolCollectionName = "school_users/\(user?.uid)/events"`

I also remove the `documentListener` right before the user logs out in this function:

```
func logoutSelected() {
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: "Are you sure you want to logout?", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    let logoutAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Logout", style: .default) { (logoutAction) in
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        
        
        self.listener.documentListener?.remove()
        print("Document Listener removed.")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
            do {
                try firebaseAuth.signOut()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.SchoolLogout, sender: self)
            } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                print("There was an error signing the user out. \(signOutError)")
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(logoutAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now this is only something that happens once and when I rerun the simulator, the correct data for the current user shows up, still, a user in production wouldn't be able to comprehend what's going on, so getting rid of it completely is the only option.

I can't think of any other way to fix this, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically what I did was remove the `Constants` value out of the paths, and now it works fine, but the app is still buggy, sometimes it'll allow me to click on some buttons, sometimes it won't.